# Select rows searching with an id in a column that contains multiple ids separated by a comma

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, sql-like

I have a column in mysql db that contain multiple ids separated by a comma like so... 100,112,324 . The column is defined as varchar.

I want to find those rows whose ids  column contains the id 112 or some other id that I specify. Similar questions I have found suggest splitting up the values in the column using lengthy code. Maybe I'm wrong but I would think there is a cleaner approach. Here is what I'm attempting to do, any help is appreciated...

```
<?php

include "../connect.php";
$usrid = "%112%";

$stm = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE ids LIKE ?");
$stm->execute($usrid);
while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['consultant']."<br>";
}

?>
```

I get a blank page as is.

Comment: Try to surround question mark with single quates like:   $stm = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE ids LIKE '?'");

Comment: I'm not sure about PDO, but in MySQLi, prepared statement placeholders `?` should not be put in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [PDO prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

Try putting the "*to be binded variable*" in an array:

```
$stm->execute(array($usrid));
```

Comment: based on a quick test that seems to do the trick. A Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes for LIKE query, because you have data type as varchar.
Try this:
`$stm = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE ids LIKE '?'");
$stm->execute($usrid);`